# Java: Find NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception

Is there a way to find out where a NullPointerException is coming from?

The compiler tells me the line it occurs, of cause, but I don't know what's wrong.
I would like to be able to find that out on my own in the future.

In this case I am calling `sorter.setNumbers(sortArray);` where `sorter` is an instance of the interface `Sorter` and I have the method `setNumbers(int [] numbers){}` in `CountingSort` which implements `Sorter`.

The first few lines of the compiler error are as follows

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyCanvas.setSortArray(MyCanvas.java:81)
    at SearchComparator$1.actionPerformed(SearchComparator.java:108)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
```

Comment: Please, post your code of MyCanvas

Comment: With line numbers of course :)

Comment: This isn't that hard.  You have a line.  Either insert println statements or stop on the line and use the debugger to display all the object references the line uses.  Only if none of them are null would you have a case meriting asking someone else for help.

Comment: I know. I'm new to this and not very familiar with the tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyCanvas.setSortArray(MyCanvas.java:81)
```

and that line is

```
sorter.setNumbers(sortArray);
```

then `sorter` must be `null`. That is the only place in that line where a method on an object is called that can be null. Passing a `null` down to `setNumbers` can not generate a `NullPointerException` in this line.

If `sortArray` is null and that causes this exception inside `setNumbers` you would see in the stacktrace that it happens in there.

---

There are two reasons why you can get a `NullPointerException`.

- You can explicitly throw it. E.g. you do `throw new NullPointerException()` (or even `throw null` which actually causes a `NullPointerException` and therefore throws one)
- You try to do something with an `Object` although it is `null`.

"Do something" in the second case can be

- call an instance method - the pattern to look for is `canThisBeNull.something(`
- accessing a field - pattern here is just `canThisBeNull.foo`
- access a `null` array's `length` property - `canThisArrayBeNull.length`
- access a `null` array's content - `canThisArrayBeNull[X]`

Note on "instance method" - there is no error if the method is `static` since you actually don't access the method through the object.

You can also have tricky to find cases. E.g. consider:

```
int value = this.getValue();
```

`this` can't be `null` and primitives can't throw. So how could there be a `NullPointerException`? The solution is auto(un)boxing:

```
private Integer getValue() {
    return null;
}
```

The compiler will automatically turn your line into

```
int value = getValue().intValue();
```

to convert the `Integer` which can be `null` into an `int`. Calling `null.intValue()` will then cause that Exception.

So to find a `NullPointerException`, look at top most line in the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException` (go down all the `caused by` clauses until you are at the bottom)

In that line look for dots. Then check if anything on the left side of a dot can be `null`.

Comment: I see. I wasn't sure if the exception is thrown when faulty code is called first or where it actually happened. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sorter` variable is probably null, either it's unset or some line override it to null.

Answer (score 0):

NUll pointer occurs when you call a method which is pointing a null,then null pointer exception comes